# Space in filename prevents downloading

Tags: java, android

I am creating an Android app, where I should be able to upload download files. I am facing a problem which I am unable to figure out, so I am here to get some help.

The problem is the following one:

- If I upload a file (let's say, for example, `firstpart secondpart fourthpart (mirchi Murga).mp3`, the file is successfully uploaded to the server.
- If I try to download this same file, I got a `FileNotFound` exception.
- If I try to download a file without spaces (example, `mirchi_Murga.mp3`) previously uploaded, then it is downloaded successfully.

So I guessed the problem would lie in the presence of white spaces in the path of the downloaded file. Anyone can help me about this issue (or correct me if i guessed wrong) ?

Thank you

Comment: how did you implement the download logic?

Comment: when you download it, do you replace whitespaces with **%20**?

Comment: use %20 in urls. as it indicates space in web urls. so replace white space with %20 during json building time.

Answer (score 1):

Thanx **`androidnoobdev`**, with your hint, i achieved the required task as--

```
url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```